# Why does my Next JS project have bad performance in Lighthouse?

Tags: performance, next.js

I created an e-commerce site [www.roomy.rs](http://www.roomy.rs). When I turn on the Lighthouse, my performance is 37.

All images are next Image component (when I download them they are webp and everything is okay), all Links are next Link component, I implemented the font in the tailwind globals part (I don't think it's a real problem) , here, for example, In index page I also used dynamic import to reduce the file size, but I can't improve the performance at all, I also tryed to delete everything from index component and performance gets better just a little bit, I think its due _app directory, and maybe with redux. is it maybe due to technology or something else, I can't hack it?

index:

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.scss";
import Header from "@/components/header";
// import Footer from "@/components/footer";
import Main from "../components/home/main";
import FlashDeals from "../components/home/flashDeals";
// import Categorye from "../components/home/category";
import SubCategory from "@/models/SubCategory";
import db from "../utils/db";
import Product from "../models/Product";
// import ProductCard from "../components/productCard";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Head from "next/head";
import HeaderTags from "@/components/home/headerTags/HeaderTags";
import SaleCode from "@/components/home/saleCode/SaleCode";
const Categorye = dynamic(() => import("../components/home/category"));
const ProductCard = dynamic(() => import("../components/productCard"));
const Footer = dynamic(() => import("@/components/footer"), { ssr: false });

export default function Home({ products }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>
        Anime majice, cene i rasprodaja za 2023. godinu - Roomy
        </title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/roomy.ico" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="100% povrat novca ukoliko Vam se majica ne svidi iz bilo kog razloga! Besplatna i brza dostava! Pronađite majicu sa svojim omiljenim anime junakom."
        />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <div className={styles.home}>
        <SaleCode />
        <HeaderTags />
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Main />
          <FlashDeals products={products} />
          {/* <AdvantageSlider/> */}
          <div className={styles.home__category}>
            <Categorye
              header="Naruto Majice"
              products={products.filter(
                (product) =>
                  product?.subCategories[0]?.name === "Naruto"
              )}
              background="#11182c"
              slug={`/majice?category=649fef8a1b7123904696900e`}
            />
              <Categorye
                header="One Piece Majice"
                products={products.filter(
                  (product) => product?.subCategories[0]?.name === "One Piece"
                )}
                background="#11182c"
                slug={`/majice?category=649fef8a1b7123904696900e`}
              />
            <Categorye
              header="AOT Majice"
              products={products.filter(
                (product) => product?.subCategories[0]?.name === "AOT"
              )}
              background="#11182c"
              slug={`/majice?category=649fef8a1b7123904696900e`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.products} justify-center`}>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <ProductCard product={product} key={product._id} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

// export async function getStaticProps() {
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  db.connectDb();
  let products = await Product.find()
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate({
      path: "subCategories",
      model: SubCategory,
      select: "name",
    })
    .select("name subProducts slug subCategories")
    .lean();

  return {
    props: {
      products: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products)),
    },
  };
}
```

_app:

```
import "@/styles/globals.scss";
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Script from "next/script";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Toastify = dynamic(() => import("@/components/toastify/Toastify"), { ssr: false });

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Toastify />
          <Script
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID}`}
          />

          <Script id="google-analytics" strategy="afterInteractive">
            {`
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '${process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID}');
    `}
          </Script>

          <Script
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GOOGLE_ADS_ID}`}
          />
          <Script id="google-campaign" strategy="afterInteractive">
            {`
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${process.env.GOOGLE_ADS_ID}');
            `}
          </Script>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Analytics />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to [analyze your bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer). This will help you figure out where any large js is loaded and may affect your page scrore.

Comment: My bundle for index.js is okay, Could the bundle size of other pages affect the performance of index.js? @FabioNettis

Comment: What does "ok" mean? How big is the page? And yes other pages could affect load times due to prefetching of the other pages when using the `Link` component.

Comment: index  - 10.7 kB 167 kB , _app -  0 B 102 kB @FabioNettis

Comment: 167 kB is quite massive, you should take a look at your bundle again and optimize, btw I ran a lighthouse test on your page and you scored an average of 92m, that is quite acceptable.

Comment: Maybe you didn't use incognito mode. My score is bad on Vercel Speed Insights and Lighthouse both. I didn't know that information for the Link component. I'm trying to fix it now. Can we make contact? I don't know if these messages are spam on the stack. @FabioNettis